# Bazel build generates a ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format" when trying to upload to Testflight

Tags: ios, bazel

A third-party library we use is generating a

> ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle
>   "thirdparty.framework" isn’t consistent with the Mach-O in the main
>   bundle. The main bundle Mach-O contains arm64(machine code), while the
>   nested bundle Mach-O contains arm64(machine code) and arm64(machine
>   code) and arm64(machine code) and arm64(machine code) and
>   arm64(machine code). Verify that all of the targets for a platform
>   have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting."

when we attempt to push to Testflight. We have enabled bitcode for all other libs and even tried *bitcode_strip*. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by ensuring that this third party library was included as a static framework in the BUILD file.

```
    apple_static_framework_import(
    name = ...,
    framework_imports = ...,
)
```